# Re-asking a question

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, best-practices

There have been a few cases where I've asked a question on StackOverflow, and received a number of good responses which then made me realize that there was a much better/clearer/more concise way to to ask my original question. I know I can edit my original question, but I'm always hesitant to rewrite the original question for fear that parts or all of the current responses will no longer make sense.

What is the preferred course of action when this happens? Should I just post an entirely new question? Or edit the existing question, which may very likely lead to the current responses no longer making sense?

Answer (score 7):

Don't edit the existing question text .Instead append any clarifications you need to make after it. There is nothing gets answerers as wound up as seeming to have written an answer that appears not to address the question, because the question's meaning was changed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't re-ask the question.  Edit the original, and leave as much of the original as you think is necessary to give context to responses.