# How to refactor a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was wondering what is the correct approach in case I ask a question and, through the comments and answers other people give, I realize that my question wasn't formulated correctly, or even that I asked the wrong question, because I asked one thing when in fact I wanted to ask another. 

In this case, I would like to reformulate the entire question, changing the title and everything. What should I do? Edit the current question (and put a commentary explaining why I changed the whole text) or start a new question, and put a link in the old one to the new one?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37870/re-asking-a-question

Comment: Should've looked harder for a duplicate.

Comment: @dsetton - the built in search isn't brilliant so it's not surprising you didn't find a duplicate straight away.

Comment: Shouldn't the IDE have a "Refactor" menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start a new question. Whatever you do, don't edit your original question so that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And what about linking the old question to the new one? I mean, just so people who enter the page know that the question wasn't abandoned, it just.. changed to a new location.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If there are already answers, *which answer the original question*, I'd let it be and ask a new question.

If there are no answers, you can either

- delete the old question, ask a new one
- edit the question

Which solution you choose depends on how much different the new question is from the old one, I think it's hard to answer this without any examples.

About comments: I don't think you have to explain it in the comments, if someone is interested he/she could just look up the edit history. Outdated information isn't usually interesting for most of your readers.

It could be nice though, to reply in a comment to the person who found out about your mistake, just to let them know you appreciate their comment.