# Suggest tags from the top search bar when text search start with the character "["

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, autocomplete

It would be comfortable or convenient when text search in the top search bar start with the character "[", the tags containing the text after "[" character are suggested.

It is true that this approach was made several years ago [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107094/tag-completion-in-search-bar), but the Stack network has evolved, I consider it convenient to suggest the existing tags that could be the most popular, similar to what happens from the tags field when formulating a new question.

Comment: What "text below"? What "text" are you "starting"? I can't quite understand the what it is you're requesting to happen

Comment: @bobble If I understand correctly, the OP wants to get auto-complete dropdown suggestions after typing `[` followed by one or more letters in the search bar. IOW, similar to what happens when you start typing in the tags field of a question.

Comment: @bobble, exactly. sorry for my English.

Comment: It's fair to reask this question, the first time was over a decade ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107094/282094 --- there are a couple of such requests: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search+autocomplete

Comment: @Rob no. Time is not a factor.

Comment: Sha, it is too.

Comment: @Rob no. Nothing changed, and even if it did, proper way would be to edit the original request.

Comment: @Sha, There seems to be a difference between some answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232300/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20042/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287241/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179819/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135003/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37870/282094 and the Help file: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @Rob Meta is different, it works in different ways than the Q&A sites of Stack Exchange. I can look for links, but I won't find anything that you didn't read already.